# Reason for Magento 2 update path?

Tags: magento2, nginx

In Magento `nginx` sample config, there is path for update. What is usage for this path?

```
# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento has configurations for both Apache and Nginx ready to use for production.
The reason why Magento team offer these configurations out of the box is for security reasons.

If you check the folder update you will notice that there are these files/folders

- app -> folder
- dev -> folder
- pub -> folder
- vart -> folder
- .gitignore -> file
- .htaccess -> file
- composer.json -> file
- composer.lock -> file
- cron.php -> file
- index.php -> file
- README.md -> file

The only accessible file in here is `index.php` and the `pub` folder. These are required to run the **update** operation and should be accessible.

The other file should not be accessible from user browser as for example exposing `composer.json` or `composer.lock` would tell the `bad guys` the version of some PHP packages installed and by using an exploit that might be on one of these packages it will try to harm your site.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I want to know what update operation does? I didn't find anything by googling it.

Comment: if you try running it it will display this message. **Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters.
To use the Magento setup wizard sign into your Admin account and navigate to System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard.** Web Setup Wizard makes you possible to install/update magento components.